# How to run tns run ios on device?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, code-signing, apple-developer

### I am trying to use `tns run ios` with iPhone

- I can run my app in the simulator.
- I have added a developer account to Xcode.
- I have added `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 9SASALAS4;` line to **build.xcconfig** file

When I connect real iPhone device and run `tns run ios` ...

it says:

```
error: Revoke certificate: Your account already has an Apple Development signing certificate for this machine, but its private key is not installed in your keychain. Xcode can create a new one after revoking your existing certificate. (in target 'sebmobil' from project 'sebmobil')
error: No profiles for 'com.ceaan.seb' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.ceaan.seb'. (in target 'sebmobil' from project 'sebmobil')
```

What's the reason for **Revoke certificate** error?

Does project name `sebmobil` have to be same with nativescript.id in package.json  ?

I don't have **sebpobil** text in my code.

Why does Xcode things project name is **sebpobil** ?

#### I am looking for an updated iOS Code Signing Walkthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was telling everything needed.
Sign in with your Apple ID

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources
2. Revoke your existing Certificates
3. Create new iOS Development Certificate
4. Create new App Identifier (description: sebappmobil , Bundle    ID:com.cemkaan.sebapp)
5. Add Device
6. Add Profile

Answer (score 1):

It may be that two computers try to use the same development certificate, and the other computer renewed your certificate. Your certificate is revoked. Apple tells you that you can renew the certificate (just press the right button); that other computer will than have a revoked certificate.

The account admin can set you up to have your own certificate.